# (Css) Table in a table alignment: how do I fix this?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, alignment

So I'm trying to show a mini-table after you click the (+) icon on the left most side of each row in a table. The problem is my alignment comes out to be all messed up and I've tried a dozen of things and still it does not work. Here is how it messes up when I click the + sign:

[image: normal table]
[image: after clicking + icon]

Here's the code for rendering the table data:

```
 const renderTableData = () => {
    return props.data.map((item: any, i: number) => {
      return (
        <tr key={i}>
          <td>
// multiple headers like the checkbox, + sign, etc
           </td>

          {rowList.includes(i) ? (
            <Table striped>
              <tbody>{renderInsideTable(props.details, item)}</tbody>
            </Table>
          ) : null}
        </tr>
      );
    });
  };
```

And for the inside table:

```
const renderInsideTable = (data: any, item: any) => {
    return data.map((dat: any, i: number) => (
      <tr key={i}>
        <td>
          <FormattedMessage id={dat.id} />
        </td>
        <td>{item[dat.id]}</td>
      </tr>
    ));
  };
```

Comment: this is the problem of CSS, where is the css? please come with snippet

Comment: I think you are posting the same question again?

Comment: @Nisharg Shah I posted it with react tags and a user suggested that I post it with css tags because it's an alignment problem. I understand its not css but I think this can be solved with css but I have trouble doing so.